# Enable Nokia Music Mix Radio on Lumia 800

Tags: music, lumia

I have a new Nokia Lumia 800 and would like to enable *Nokia Music Mix Radio* on it.

It just was [released in two more countries (Germany and Switzerland)](http://wmpoweruser.com/nokia-music-mix-radio-released-for-german-lumia-device-owners/), and from the reviews in the marketplace it should be working.

On my device, however, I do not get the new option in the Nokia Music App.

I tried so far:

- Firmware updates
- Nokia application updates (especially Nokia Music of course)
- Changed temporarily system locale and language to German/Switzerland, English/UK

I still do not have the mix radio option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My last idea was successful, and it's actually simple: Uninstalled Nokia Music, and reinstalled it from the Nokia section in marketplace.

It seems as if the application retains the phone region settings that were used when the application was first started. Looks like my phone was set to a country to which Nokia Music Mix radio was unavailable, hence uninstall/install to have it recheck.